# DataScraping a website, retrieved data from its multiple pages and the output stored in the form of lists, how to store this variable data in xml file

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

While data scraping, my code is traversing through multiple pages of a website and getting data and storing it in the form of lists. I'm then converting it into dataframes and trying to store it in csv file but what I'm getting is just the last list of the output.
P.S. Size or length of the list is also variable.

Here's an excerpt of the code.

```
for product in products:
                    prod = 'https://www.intel.com' + product['href']
                    html_text4 = requests.get(prod).text
                    soup4 = BeautifulSoup(html_text4, 'lxml')
                    processors3 = soup4.find_all('div', {'class' : 'add-compare-wrap'})
                    for processor3 in processors3:
                        proc3 = 'https://www.intel.com' + processor3.a['href']
                        web6 = 'https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/201889/intel-core-i310325-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-70-ghz/specifications.html'
                        web7 = 'https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/197123/intel-core-i31000g4-processor-4m-cache-up-to-3-20-ghz/specifications.html'
                        web8 = 'https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/97930/intel-atom-processor-c3508-8m-cache-up-to-1-60-ghz/specifications.html'
                        if ((proc3 != web6) and (proc3 != web7) and (proc3 != web8)):
                            html_text5 = requests.get(proc3).text
                            soup5 = BeautifulSoup(html_text5, 'lxml')
                            essentials = soup5.find('div', {'id' : 'specs-1-0-0'}).find_all('div', {'class' : 'row tech-section-row'})
                            cpu_specifications = soup5.find('div', {'id' : 'specs-1-0-1'}).find_all('div', {'class' : 'row tech-section-row'})
                            package = soup5.find_all('div', {'class' : 'tech-section'})
                            list1 = []
                            list2 = []
                            list3 = []
                            for ess in essentials:
                                essential = ess.text
                                list1.append(essential)
                            for cpu in cpu_specifications:
                                cpu_specification = cpu.text
                                list2.append(cpu_specification)
                            for p in package:
                                p2 = p.find_all('h3')
                                x= 'Package Specifications'
                                for p3 in p2:
                                    p4 = p3.text
                                if (p4==x):
                                    p3 = p.find_all('div', {'class' : 'row tech-section-row'})
                                    for package_specifications in p3:
                                        package_specification = package_specifications.text
                                        list3.append(package_specification)
                            list4 = list1 + list2 + list3
                            df = pd.DataFrame(list4)
                            df.to_csv('file.csv', header=False,index=False)
```

I want the entire output to get stored in the csv file.

Answer (score 1):

Think it is just an indentation error as you are rewriting your file over and over again with each loop so it will always show the last iteration.

I believe if you use the below it will work as expected

```
# added this in as the overall dataframe you want to add to
# outside of loop as it looks like you want all products to go into the dataframe
final_df = pd.DataFrame() 
for product in products:
    prod = 'https://www.intel.com' + product['href']
    html_text4 = requests.get(prod).text
    soup4 = BeautifulSoup(html_text4, 'lxml')
    processors3 = soup4.find_all('div', {'class' : 'add-compare-wrap'})
    for processor3 in processors3:
        proc3 = 'https://www.intel.com' + processor3.a['href']
        web6 = 'https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/201889/intel-core-i310325-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-70-ghz/specifications.html'
        web7 = 'https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/197123/intel-core-i31000g4-processor-4m-cache-up-to-3-20-ghz/specifications.html'
        web8 = 'https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/97930/intel-atom-processor-c3508-8m-cache-up-to-1-60-ghz/specifications.html'
        if ((proc3 != web6) and (proc3 != web7) and (proc3 != web8)):
            html_text5 = requests.get(proc3).text
            soup5 = BeautifulSoup(html_text5, 'lxml')
            essentials = soup5.find('div', {'id' : 'specs-1-0-0'}).find_all('div', {'class' : 'row tech-section-row'})
            cpu_specifications = soup5.find('div', {'id' : 'specs-1-0-1'}).find_all('div', {'class' : 'row tech-section-row'})
            package = soup5.find_all('div', {'class' : 'tech-section'})
            list1 = []
            list2 = []
            list3 = []
            for ess in essentials:
                essential = ess.text
                list1.append(essential)
            for cpu in cpu_specifications:
                cpu_specification = cpu.text
                list2.append(cpu_specification)
            for p in package:
                p2 = p.find_all('h3')
                x= 'Package Specifications'
                for p3 in p2:
                    p4 = p3.text
                if (p4==x):
                    p3 = p.find_all('div', {'class' : 'row tech-section-row'})
                    for package_specifications in p3:
                        package_specification = package_specifications.text
                        list3.append(package_specification)
            list4 = list1 + list2 + list3
            # adding list to final dataframe
            final_df.loc[len(final_df)] = list4

# moving saving to file outside of loop so that all products data is captured in the file
final_df.to_csv('file.csv', header=False,index=False)
```

Just fixed the overall indentation.
Hope this helps!

Comment: ValueError: cannot set a frame with no defined columns

Comment: In this part
```final_df = pd.DataFrame()``` add a variable of columns and put the columns you need in. For example ```final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1','col2','col3'])```